# How to create a data frame from a substring in R?

Tags: r

I have a table which tells me if a client paid in cash or not and what she/he bought:

```
Client | Item | Cash 
___________________________
John   | CD   | Yes
Billy  | LP   | Yes
Charles| DVD  | 
Mary   | CD   | Yes
Lucy   | Book | 
Sam    | DVD  | 
Louis  | CD   | Yes
Mario  | LP   | Yes
```

And then, I want to create a dataframe only with the clients who paid in cash. Like this:

```
Client | Item | Cash 
___________________________
John   | CD   | Yes
Billy  | LP   | Yes
Mary   | CD   | Yes
Louis  | CD   | Yes
Mario  | LP   | Yes
```

I tried this:

```
df %>%
  group_by(cash)
```

Comment: Please check out [`dplyr`'s documentation](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/index.html) and review one or more R tutorials. If you google it, you'll find many good resources to learn R.

Answer (score 0):

You need to filter the rows where the payment is in Cash

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% filter(Cash=="Yes")
```

The `group_by` function is useful if after you want to summarise the data by group (Cash or not): compute sums, counts, means...